# Write list r function to iterate on dataframe columns

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R, and am trying to improve in writing code that is as efficient / pretty as possible.

I have been tasked with the following:
*Check the missing values of the "Age" and "Name" attributes of dataset train.csv.*

I would like to produce the indices of missing values for each column in a separate list element. I wrote the following code to do this.

```
list(which(is.na(train$Age)))
list(which(is.na(train$Name)))
```

My gut tells me that if you are many writing several iterations of the same line of code, you probably don't know the language very well (any objections?). I was able to condense the above using "apply", but this function operates on *all* columns and not exclusively on the two of interest.

```
apply(train, 2, function(x) which(is.na(x)))
```

I could, alternatively, create a new dataframe with just these two columns, but that defeats the purpose of this question altogether...

Thanks very much in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run your apply only on the columns of interest, you can change

```
apply(train, 2, function(x) which(is.na(x)))
```

to

```
apply(train[,c("Age", "Name")], 2, function(x) which(is.na(x)))
```

Extra explanation: `train[,c("Age", "Name")]` takes *all* the rows from `train` (nothing before the `,`) and only the columns "Age" and "Name" (list of columns to keep after the `,`)

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

To create a function, you can use your statement and modify as follows:

```
train <- data.frame(Age = c(NA,"x100",NA), Name = c("b","c",NA))

my.is.na <- function(data.colname){
  apply(train[names(train) == data.colname], 2, function(x) which(is.na(x)))
}
```

Then you can just call the function by the variable name of your dataset.

```
> my.is.na("Name")
Name 
   3 
> my.is.na("Age")
     Age
[1,]   1
[2,]   3
```

Data:

```
> train
   Age Name
1 <NA>    b
2 x100    c
3 <NA> <NA>
```